# mysql: get a row for every matching condition even with the same record

Tags: mysql

I know this is weird (maybe?) But how do I get multiple rows for the same record, relative to how many condition it passed?

```
table foo
+----------+-------+
| field1   |field2 |
+----------+-------+
| 1        | 0     |
+----------+-------+

SELECT field1
FROM foo
WHERE field1 = 1 OR field2 = 0
```

I want it to return

```
+----------+
| field1   |
+----------+
| 1        |
| 1        |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to break the conditions in the `where` clause and use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT field1
 FROM foo
 WHERE field1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT field1
 FROM foo
 WHERE field2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do something like this:

```
SELECT
  t.field1
FROM
  foo AS t
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS colID UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS x
WHERE
  x.colID = 1 AND t.field1 = 1
  OR
  x.colID = 2 AND t.field2 = 0
;
```

By cross-joining the subselect you are duplicating the rows. Each duplicate is distinguished by a `x.colID` value. Using that value you can apply every partial condition independently, as you can see done in the WHERE clause above.